# O que é o void no javascript?

Tags: javascript

Pude contemplar um código javascript que possuía o seguinte código:

```
if (context === void 0) {
   // faça algo
}
```

Não entendi o que significa esse trecho do código ou o que isso faz.

A única vez que usei o `void` foi pra criar links cegos

Assim:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link Cego</a>
```

Afinal de contas:

- O que é o void no javascript?
- O que é que está sendo verificado no primeiro exemplo, onde o `void 0` utilizado na comparação? Não seria a mesma coisa que `typeof context == 'undefined'`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É um operador construído para permitir efeitos colaterais em lugares em que é desejada uma expressão que avalie para `undefined`, mas sem o uso direto desta *variável global*. `void expr` possui a mesma equivalência que `void(expr)`, e é a menor expressão pura que avalia para `undefined`. Quando usado imediatamente após uma expressão de invocação imediata de função, pode ser usado para forçar com que a própria keyword seja tratada como uma expressão. O que faz criar links cegos em JS é que, avaliando para `undefined`, é rejeitado um redirecionamento para o navegador. A Mozilla tem uma boa documentação, que, com um pouquinho de esforço, pode ser útil: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void.

No seu exemplo, poderia comparar-se a `typeof context === 'undefined'` ou `context === undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

O operador `void` avalia uma expressão como `undefined`. no caso `void 0`, ele avalia o valor 0 como undefined. Neste caso `void 1`, `void 2`, `void (1 + 2)` e `void Math.round(12.5)`, ambos são avaliados como `undefined`. No caso do exemplo ele esta comparando o valor da variavel context com undefined.  Utilizar void 0 é uma convenção, eu sinceramente não sei o porque dela.

Você tem que ficar atento a ordem de precendencia do operador, pois `void (1 + 2)` produz `undefined`, entretanto `void 1 + 2` produz `NaN`.

Answer (score -10):

Este operador permite a inserção de expressões que produzem efeitos secundários em lugares onde uma expressão que avalia a ação {{jsxref("Global_Objects/undefined", "indefinida")}} é desejada.

O operador void é muitas vezes utilizado apenas para obter o valor primitivo indefinido, geralmente usando "void(0)" (o que equivale a "void 0"). Nestes casos, a variável global {{jsxref("Global_Objects/undefined", "indefinida")}} pode ser utilizado em vez (supondo que ele não tenha sido atribuído a um valor não-padrão).

Chamada imediata das expressões da função
Quando usamos uma Chamada imediata das expressões da função, valores nulos podem ser usado para forçar a palavra-chave da função a ser tratada como uma expressão em vez de uma declaração.

```
void function iife() {
    var bar = function () {};
    var baz = function () {};
    var foo = function () {
        bar();
        baz();
     };
    var biz = function () {};

    foo();
    biz();
}();
```

JavaScript URIs
When a browser follows a javascript: URI, it evaluates the code in the URI and then replaces the contents of the page with the returned value, unless the returned value is {{jsxref("Global_Objects/undefined", "undefined")}}. The void operator can be used to return {{jsxref("Global_Objects/undefined", "undefined")}}. For example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
  Clique aqui para não fazer nada
</a>

<a href="javascript:void(document.body.style.backgroundColor='green');">
  Clique aqui para o papel de parede ser verde
</a>
```

Comment: Quando se copia o conteúdo de algum lugar, é interessante informar a fonte neste caso, a MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void). Adicionalmente, sua resposta contém conteúdo não traduzido.

Comment: Desculpa é que eu sou novo novo aqui